# express/ejs app, Navbar svg images not loading on some pages?

Tags: css, express, ejs

So, my navbar is saved as a partial in a fairly straightforward express app.  I have the navbar also included in a boilerplate wrapper which is being used on most pages, like so:

```
<h1>HELLO<h1>
```

and in the boilerplate file I have
`<%- include("../partials/navbar")%>`

The problem is that the navbar shows up but the two .svg images don't show on certain pages, which to my eye are using the exact same format. Does anyone have any ideas what the problem might be?

Also, please let me know if I can clarify anything - I'm quite fresh to coding so I'm a bit limited in my vocabulary.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT(nowhere near enough infomation, sorry):

here is the code for navbar partial:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top navbar-dark">
    <a href="/"> <img class="brand" src="logo.svg" alt="" /></a>
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                
                <a class="nav-link ms-3" href="/events">Upcoming Events</a>
                <a class="nav-link ms-3" href="/events/new">New Event</a>
                <a class="nav-link ms-3" href="/community">Community</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto rightLinks" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                
                <% if(!currentUser) { %>
                <p><%= currentUser %></p>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>

                <% } else { %>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                <p class="nav-link">
                    <%=currentUser.username %><img class="profileIcon" src="profile.svg"></img>
                </p>
                <% } %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and here is the boilerplate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style2.css" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
        <link
            href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />

        <title>Street Music</title>
    </head>
    <body class="flex-column">
        <%- include("../partials/navbar")%>
        <main class="containter vw-100"><%- body %></main>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bs-custom-file-input/dist/bs-custom-file-input.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.0/axios.js"></script>

        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>

        <!-- <script src="/javascripts/validateForms.js"></script> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Maybe I should mention that the pages in which the images show up are in the same directory, and the images themselves are in public.

Each file begins with <% layout("layouts/boilerplate") %> but it only displays the images on certain pages.

Comment: Can you show your code? There is no way we can know what those .svg images are, where you placed them and why they don't show

Answer (score 0):

first:-

img tag doesn`t have a closed tag so this is wrong

```
<img class="profileIcon" src="profile.svg"></img>
```

you should delete the closed tag to be like that

```
<img class="profileIcon" src="profile.svg">
```

second:-
you mentioned that the images is in anther directory and you didn`t route them in src

```
src="profile.svg"
```

to make the route correctly there is two ways :-
first :-

```
src="../public/profile.svg"
```

second:-
if you use express ,you can do static file to your public file in server.js like so

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

and then you can route directly to the public directory

```
src="./public/profile.svg"
```